# Do Longbow Grenades teleport, or not?

Tags: borderlands-series

[The Wiki](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Longbow_(grenade)) says that Longbow Grenades don't really teleport, but just travel really, really fast.

But I think they're using a different idea of teleport than me. "Instanteous traversal of space" vs. my "Traversal of space without actually crossing the intervening, even if there's a delay".

The important bit, is, if, after the teleport animation, if something comes between the start and end point that wasn't there before, if the grenade lands at the bottom of the intervening object, being stopped by it, or if it isn't stopped by it and therefore doesn't interact with "conventional" space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I experienced, longbow grenades do **not** teleport.

If something like an enemy cuts the "warp-line" after the longbow animation is launched the grenade would **end its flight at the enemy as it pops off it**.

Grenade mods with the throwing type **longbow / lungboom** also cannot surpass fixed obstacles, even if there is an area behind where it could possibly land.

Imagine aiming at a closed door, the grenade would bounce off (or stick on it, if it features the **sticky / stik** accessory) but would not "beam" itself into the room behind.

It often seemed to me, that the grenade goes "through the enemy" too. But in fact I just missed them by a few inches as and some enemies, like for example rats, a very nimble and have a sleek hitbox.

So **it might occur that an enemy will stop your longbow grenades flight but it might happen very rarely**. It could happen more likely at bulky enemies like a Goliath, but in general, using Explosives against Goliaths is not the best idea if you are not up for a decent brawl.

Some useful extra: **longbow** grenades of all types go very well with the **sticky** accessory. This way you can attach for example a ***"lungboom stik sluj murrv"*** (I love bandit namings) to one enemy without exposing yourself and - by a bit of luck - have them slagged so you dont have to switch weapons in order to deal double damage.